# How to change color of spans with the same top position, but not the siblings above or below

Tags: jquery, html, css

How to change color of spans with the same top position, but not the sibling elements above or below in a paragraph composed of spans?

I've a paragraph generated by `span` tags and have started to figure out how to change the color of the line of `span` that have a `span` with an appended class of `.active`

What would be a good way to accomplish this?

```js
var next = $(".active").next();
var prev = $(".active").prev();

var activeWord = $(".active");
while ((next.position().top && prev.position().top) === activeWord.position().top) {
  next.css({
    color: "red"
  });
  prev.css({
    color: "red"
  });
}
```

```css
.word {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.25em;
}
.active {
  color: red;
}
.active-row {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="content">
  <span class="word">Lorem</span>  <span class="word">ipsum</span>  <span class="word">dolor</span>  <span class="word">sit amet</span>  <span class="word">consectetur</span>  <span class="word">adipiscing</span>  <span class="word">elit</span>  <span class="word">sed</span> 
  <span
  class="word">do</span> <span class="word">eiusmod</span>  <span class="word">tempor</span>  <span class="word">incididunt</span>  <span class="word">ut</span>  <span class="word">labore</span>  <span class="word">et</span>  <span class="word">dolore</span>  <span class="word">magna</span> 
    <span
    class="word">aliqua</span> <span class="word">Ut</span>  <span class="word">enim</span>  <span class="word">ad</span>  <span class="word">minim</span>  <span class="word">veniam</span>  <span class="word">quis</span>  <span class="word">nostrud</span>  <span class="word">exercitation</span> 
      <span
      class="word">ullamco</span> <span class="word">laboris</span>  <span class="word">nisi</span>  <span class="word">ut</span>  <span class="active word">aliquip</span>
        <span class="word">ex</span>  <span class="word">ea</span>  <span class="word">commodo</span>  <span class="word">consequat</span>  <span class="word">Duis</span>  <span class="word">aute</span>  <span class="word">irure</span>  <span class="word">dolor</span> 
        <span
        class="word">in</span> <span class="word">reprehenderit</span>  <span class="word">in</span>  <span class="word">voluptate</span>  <span class="word">velit</span>  <span class="word">esse</span>  <span class="word">cillum</span>  <span class="word">dolore</span>  <span class="word">eu</span> 
          <span
          class="word">fugiat</span> <span class="word">nulla</span>  <span class="word">pariatur</span>  <span class="word">Excepteur</span>  <span class="word">sint</span>  <span class="word">occaecat</span>  <span class="word">cupidatat</span>  <span class="word">non</span> 
            <span
            class="word">proident</span> <span class="word">sunt</span>  <span class="word">in</span>  <span class="word">culpa</span>  <span class="word">qui</span>  <span class="word">officia</span>  <span class="word">deserunt</span>  <span class="word">mollit</span>  <span class="word">anim</span> 
              <span
              class="word">id</span> <span class="word">est</span>  <span class="word">laborum</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you should not be checking the previous and next element at the same time (and your code was not even doing that, because `(next.position().top && prev.position().top)` would just result in true or false) - because an element might have only one sibling on the same line, but the other on the previous or next line.

And secondly, you forgot to *advance* next and prev for the next iteration.

```js
var next = $(".active").next();
var prev = $(".active").prev();

var activeWordPositionTop = $(".active").position().top; // Let's cache this value,
                                  // instead of fetching it in each iteration again

while (next.position().top === activeWordPositionTop) {
  next.css({
    color: "red"
  });
  next = next.next(); // advance to the next element of the current one
}
while (prev.position().top === activeWordPositionTop) {
  prev.css({
    color: "red"
  });
  prev = prev.prev();  // advance to the previous element of the current one
}
```

```css
.word {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.25em;
}
.active {
  color: red;
}
.active-row {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="content">
  <span class="word">Lorem</span> <span class="word">Lorem</span> <span class="word">Lorem</span>  <span class="word">ipsum</span>  <span class="word">dolor</span>  <span class="word">sit amet</span>  <span class="word">consectetur</span>  <span class="word">adipiscing</span>  <span class="word">elit</span>  <span class="word">sed</span> 
  <span
  class="word">do</span> <span class="word">eiusmod</span>  <span class="word">tempor</span>  <span class="word">incididunt</span>  <span class="word">ut</span>  <span class="word">labore</span>  <span class="word">et</span>  <span class="word">dolore</span>  <span class="word">magna</span> 
    <span
    class="word">aliqua</span> <span class="word">Ut</span>  <span class="word">enim</span>  <span class="word">ad</span>  <span class="word">minim</span>  <span class="word">veniam</span>  <span class="word">quis</span>  <span class="word">nostrud</span>  <span class="word">exercitation</span> 
      <span
      class="word">ullamco</span> <span class="word">laboris</span>  <span class="word">nisi</span>  <span class="word">ut</span>  <span class="active word">aliquip</span>
        <span class="word">ex</span>  <span class="word">ea</span>  <span class="word">commodo</span>  <span class="word">consequat</span>  <span class="word">Duis</span>  <span class="word">aute</span>  <span class="word">irure</span>  <span class="word">dolor</span> 
        <span
        class="word">in</span> <span class="word">reprehenderit</span>  <span class="word">in</span>  <span class="word">voluptate</span>  <span class="word">velit</span>  <span class="word">esse</span>  <span class="word">cillum</span>  <span class="word">dolore</span>  <span class="word">eu</span> 
          <span
          class="word">fugiat</span> <span class="word">nulla</span>  <span class="word">pariatur</span>  <span class="word">Excepteur</span>  <span class="word">sint</span>  <span class="word">occaecat</span>  <span class="word">cupidatat</span>  <span class="word">non</span> 
            <span
            class="word">proident</span> <span class="word">sunt</span>  <span class="word">in</span>  <span class="word">culpa</span>  <span class="word">qui</span>  <span class="word">officia</span>  <span class="word">deserunt</span>  <span class="word">mollit</span>  <span class="word">anim</span> 
              <span
              class="word">id</span> <span class="word">est</span>  <span class="word">laborum</span>
</div>
```

(I added two more Lorems at the beginning, because in your example the active word `aliquip` just happend to be the first word on its line in the standard width of the code snippet box - with it being a litte more to the center it becomes more obvious the code does what it should.)

Comment: I knew I was missing something! What's with the weird .next().next() syntax? I read up on this a bit when I was experimenting, but never fully understood how this iterates.

Comment: It's not `next().next()`, but `next.next()` - important difference. The first next is just a variable name, and the second one the jQuery method name. You might as well give the variable a different name, to avoid confusion here. Start with maybe `var rightSibling = $(".active").next()`, then in the loop that becomes `rightSibling.next()` - we are simply moving from the right sibling of the starting element to the next right sibling, and the next, etc.

Comment: What if I want to also detect if the content in the span wraps to the next row? Is there a way to do this and keep the wrapped part of the text black and not red?

Comment: Maybe using the :first-line psuedo selector?

Comment: :first-line won’t work on inline elements, and if you make them something else than inline, that will change how they wrap. This really only works properly if you have one "word" per span. (And I would probably use white-space property, too, to forbid those "single words" from breaking in places like where there’s a hyphen or something.)

Answer (score 0):

Just update `prev` & `next` variables inside while loop

```js
var next = $(".active").next();
var prev = $(".active").prev();

var activeWord = $(".active");

while (next.position().top === activeWord.position().top  || prev.position().top === activeWord.position().top) {
  next.css({
    color: "red"
  });
  prev.css({
    color: "red"
  });
//just update prev & next variables
prev = next;
next = next.next();
}
```

```css
.word {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.25em;
}
.active {
  color: red;
}
.active-row {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="content">
  <span class="word">Lorem</span>  <span class="word">ipsum</span>  <span class="word">dolor</span>  <span class="word">sit amet</span>  <span class="word">consectetur</span>  <span class="word">adipiscing</span>  <span class="word">elit</span>  <span class="word">sed</span> 
  <span
  class="word">do</span> <span class="word">eiusmod</span>  <span class="word">tempor</span>  <span class="word">incididunt</span>  <span class="word">ut</span>  <span class="word">labore</span>  <span class="word">et</span>  <span class="word">dolore</span>  <span class="word">magna</span> 
    <span
    class="word">aliqua</span> <span class="word">Ut</span>  <span class="word">enim</span>  <span class="word">ad</span>  <span class="word">minim</span>  <span class="word">veniam</span>  <span class="word">quis</span>  <span class="word">nostrud</span>  <span class="word">exercitation</span> 
      <span
      class="word">ullamco</span> <span class="word">laboris</span>  <span class="word">nisi</span>  <span class="word">ut</span>  <span class="active word">aliquip</span>
        <span class="word">ex</span>  <span class="word">ea</span>  <span class="word">commodo</span>  <span class="word">consequat</span>  <span class="word">Duis</span>  <span class="word">aute</span>  <span class="word">irure</span>  <span class="word">dolor</span> 
        <span
        class="word">in</span> <span class="word">reprehenderit</span>  <span class="word">in</span>  <span class="word">voluptate</span>  <span class="word">velit</span>  <span class="word">esse</span>  <span class="word">cillum</span>  <span class="word">dolore</span>  <span class="word">eu</span> 
          <span
          class="word">fugiat</span> <span class="word">nulla</span>  <span class="word">pariatur</span>  <span class="word">Excepteur</span>  <span class="word">sint</span>  <span class="word">occaecat</span>  <span class="word">cupidatat</span>  <span class="word">non</span> 
            <span
            class="word">proident</span> <span class="word">sunt</span>  <span class="word">in</span>  <span class="word">culpa</span>  <span class="word">qui</span>  <span class="word">officia</span>  <span class="word">deserunt</span>  <span class="word">mollit</span>  <span class="word">anim</span> 
              <span
              class="word">id</span> <span class="word">est</span>  <span class="word">laborum</span>
</div>
```